# Plot a piece of a spherical shell - Wolfram Alpha website

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'd like to know how to plot a piece of a spherical shell $0.118<r<0.236$, $0<\theta<\pi$, $0<\phi<\pi/2$ by using the website Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Since you want to draw a sphere, the radius should be fixed. if we fix r=0.2, you can try "parametric plot3d {r sin(theta) cos(phi), r sin(theta) sin(phi), r cos(theta)} for r=0.2, theta=0 to pi, phi=0 to pi/2".

Comment: To @Always: A spherical shell is the region between two concentric spheres of different radiuses.

Comment: Is WolframAlpha mandatory for plotting? There are some nice examples of a spherical shell draws made by TikZ. For an instance, you may check [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471663/spherical-shell-using-tikz)

Comment: Hello @AntonVrdoljak yes I'd like to know how to do that in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: WA doesn't seem to have support for this functionality yet, but the underlying framework (Mathematica) does. You can supposedly sign up for free access to browser version of M [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/), though I'm not sure how much functionality free users have access to. At any rate, M can do it with built-in functions like [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html) or [`RegionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html)

Comment: Here's a link to a public notebook with a sample input and plot (you may or may not be able to click and drag on the plot to rotate the region) : https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/c099d788-a1dc-49b4-862f-978980afbf8c